# Most innovative Ways to break system(application) in performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, loadrunner, blazemeter

I need to break my application not with user load any other scenario's so that i can able to break my application in Performance testing. Suggest me some scenario's which i can use for my load test

Comment: Are you looking for ways to find the limits of your application?

Comment: "I need to break my application not with user load" - why? Why can't you apply a load?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be trying to "break" the application, the targets of the performance testing could be:

- Check whether your application is capable of handling **anticipated** load, i.e. if you expect 1000 concurrent users you should test if your application can handle 1000 concurrent users providing reasonable response times without any errors. This is called [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing)
- The next step could be checking if your application is capable of handling **prolonged** load, i.e. simulate 1000 concurrent users and leave the test running for several hours or even days. This is called [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) and this way you will be able to identify any [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), not closed threads, etc.
- If above testing types are successful you might want to determine the boundaries of your application capacity, i.e. determine how many concurrent users in total it will be able to serve, what are the limits, what is the first bottleneck (i.e. system starts running out of CPU/RAM/Disk, database is slow, network throughput is not enough, application code is not optimal, etc.). To determine the breaking point you should gradually increase the load from zero to the point when you will not be happy with the response times and/or throughput or the errors start occurring. Once you reach this point analyze the results and determine the root cause of the performance problem. This is called [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)

Check out [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) article for more detailed information on the above techniques.